# Is there a range limit when scanning a Simaris target?

Tags: warframe

When a teammate is scanning a daily Cephalon Simaris target (using the [synthesis scanner](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Synthesis_Scanner)), is there a range to be respected in order to benefit from the stance provided by the scan ?

It looks to me like when I'm too far from the scanned target, I don't receive the associated standing reward.  Last time it occured I was 200~250m from the target and didn't receive any Simaris standing.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be within **50 meters** of the target.

Comment: Do you have a source?

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'd be interested in a source as well.

Comment: I read it in a thread a couple of years ago and ran some tests with some friends and it seemed accurate. Do not know if this is the exact thread (https://forums.warframe.com/topic/682271-syndicate-standing-and-simlaris-standing-still-broken/ ). The official sources does not say anything related to the range. Hope this helps if you want to retest.

Comment: I had the impression it was rather up to 100m; I'll run more tests and let you know.  I validate this one in the meantime, thanks !

Comment: It should be affinity range, so anything that boosts affinity range (fosfors) should increase it, although I don't remember if they work outside of PoE